# How to run process in background with output in file after some foreground input/output actions on linux?

Tags: linux, ssh, process, console

I start a process and interact with it (some input actions) in foreground, then it works for a long time, so I put it to bg and logout. I want to redirect error messages in text file, while process in a background and I'm not connected to machine. How can I implement that?

**UPD** : I need to redirect output while process is already running, because initially I need some console output.

Comment: `cmd 2>&1 > /path/to/file.log &` this will redirect stderror to stdout  and both to a file. then it becomes a background process. with `fg` you can bring the process back to foreground.

Comment: @user163258 but initially I need stdout to console, and only after some interaction I want to redirect it with stderror to file. Is it doable? Or can I split stdout and stderror and redirect stderror to file?

Comment: `cmd 2> /path/to/file > /dev/null &` should work

Comment: @user163258 also just cmd 2>file.log doesn't work for me, stdout appends in file.log too :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start the process interactively, yet redirecting the error messgaes, via

```
  my_program 2> output.txt
```

and you can now wait for its output, interact with it, and then put it into the background, still keeping the redirection of standard error.

Comment: but what if my process use standard console output before I need it to get in background?

Comment: @infimum there is no problem, you are redirecting only standard error, not standard output.

Answer (score 1):

SSH in, start a process, and then forget about it? This sounds like a job for [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) or [screen](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNU_Screen). You can leave the process running, detach from tmux, and logout without it exiting.

You can still redirect standard error to a text file using `2> log.txt` when you run your command, and even `tail -f` the file in another tmux window.

Answer (score 0):

You want to start with error messages going (unbuffered) into the text file, then you can look at them as you want (see "tail -f"). Assuming a shell with job control, you can suspend the current job with Ctrl-Z, then "bg" to put it in the background.